# Newly created DOM Document location

Tags: javascript, html, url, domdocument

I have created a new DOM document using
    `var foo=document.implementation.createDocument(null, "html");`
and I want to set some properties, including location. But `foo.location` returns `null` and `foo.location.href="https://stackoverflow.com"` returns error `Cannot set property 'href' of null`. How can I set location?

Comment: this is because "If the current document is not in a browsing context, the returned value is null."  [browsing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Browsing_context) -- I'm not sure you can attach the `XMLDocument` returned to a new context. However that's _why_ it's happening.

Answer (score 2):

You must first establish a [browsing context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Browsing_context) for that document as @rlemon suggests.

The easiest way to provide a browsing context is to place the new document into an `iframe` element by replacing the `iframe`'s document with your new document.

This example is lifted from the MDN demo on how to do this:

```
    var frame = document.getElementById("theFrame");
    // note the use of createHTMLDocument
    var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New Document");
    var destDocument = frame.contentDocument;
    var srcNode = doc.documentElement;
    var newNode = destDocument.importNode(srcNode, true);
    destDocument.replaceChild(newNode, destDocument.documentElement);
    // Now it is in a browsing context and the location can be set
    destDocument.location.href = "//example.com";
```

I noticed you are creating an HTML document. Therefore I used `createHTMLDocument` rather than `createDocument` (which creates an `XMLDocument`).

This sample won't run as a snippet here because the `iframe` is blocked. So here is a [jsbin with this code running](https://jsbin.com/vezarobofu/1/edit?js,output).

Comment: I get error: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'location' property on 'HTMLDocument': The attribute value is not an object.`

Comment: compare your code against the jsbin I linked in the answer. I didn't use any variable named `HTMLDocument`, but that jsbin works. So if you compare what I've done to what you have, you should be able to find the issue.